# Quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Why does this isomorphism of rings hold?
> $$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]/(10/9) \cong \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$$

I honestly have no idea how this is true. How would you even approach this?

Comment: I think it should be $(10/3)$.

Comment: Hint: Since $9$ is a unit, then $(10/9) = (10)$. Now note that $3$ is already a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, so $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})[1/3] = \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn could you elaborate on the last isomorphism? The obvious choice (multiplication by $3$) has a non-trivial kernel (contains $3+\frac{1}{3}$)

Comment: @Bliipbluup As I said, $3$ is a unit since $3 \cdot 7 = 21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$. So map $1/3$ to $7$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: It seems fairly clear this is related to the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283411/step-in-showing-this-isomorphism). Are you the same user? And why not mention the connection?

Comment: @Trebor: This is clearly connected to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283411/step-in-showing-this-isomorphism), hence the $10/9$. In any case, as $3$ is a unit, $(10/9)=(10/3)=(10)=(30)=\cdots$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]\simeq\mathbb Z[x]/(3x-1)$ by sending $x$ to $1/3$. This shows that $10/9$ corresponds to $10x^2$, so $$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]/(10/9)\simeq \mathbb Z[x]/(10x^2,3x-1).$$ But $(10x^2,3x-1)=(10,3x-1)$ and then our ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]/(3x-1)$. But $(3x-1)=(x-7)$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$ and $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]/(x-7)\simeq \mathbb Z_{10}$.